# Impala create parquet table with partition from existing Kudu table

Tags: parquet, create-table, partition, hue, kudu

I'm trying to create a parquet table with partition from existing Kudu table in Impala without having to re-specify the columns with data types again.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_name.parquet_table
PARTITIONED BY (`year` SMALLINT, `month` TINYINT, `day` TINYINT)
STORED AS PARQUET 
As SELECT * FROM db_name.kudu_table limit 0
```

I get an error message saying

```
ParseException: Syntax error in line 4:undefined: As SELECT * FROM db_name.parquet_table limit 0 ^ Encountered: AS Expected CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

But When I try to create the parquet table without partition it works using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_name.parquet_table STORED AS PARQUET  
AS SELECT * FROM db_name.kudu_table LIMIT 0
```

But When I try to add partition using:

```
ALTER TABLE db_name.parquet_table ADD PARTITION(`year`=0,`month`=0,`day`=0)
```

I get the following error message:

```
AnalysisException: Table is not partitioned: db_name.parquet_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to load data with

**STATIC PARTITIONING**

One way to load data into a partitioned table is to use static partitioning,
in which you manually define the different partitions.
(The other way is to have the partitions automatically defined when you load the data, this is called Dynamic Partitioning.)

With static partitioning, you create a partition manually, using an `ALTER TABLE … ADD PARTITION` statement,
and then load the data into the partition.

With your example I would try this.

First. Create the partitioned table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_name.parquet_table(field1 [TYPE],...,fieldN [TYPE]) --Fields that not belongs to the partitioned columns
PARTITIONED BY (year SMALLINT, month TINYINT, day TINYINT)
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

Second. `ALTER TABLE` statement to create the partition.

```sql
ALTER TABLE db_name.parquet_table ADD PARTITION(year = 0,month = 0,day = 0);
```

Notice how the partition column name and the specific value that defines this partition, are both specified in the `ADD PARTITION` clause.
This creates a partition directory inside the table directory.

After the partition is created, you can add data into the partition using an `INSERT … SELECT` statement

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE db_name.parquet_table
    PARTITION(year = 0, month = 0, day = 0)
    SELECT field1,..., fieldn --do not include partitioned columns
    FROM db_name.kudu_table 
    WHERE year = 0 AND month = 0 AND day = 0;
```

With static partitioning, you need to repeat these two steps for each partition:
first create the partition, then add data.
You can actually use any method to load the data; you need not use an `INSERT` statement.
You could instead use `hdfs dfs` commands or a `LOAD DATA INPATH` command.
But however you load the data, you have to be careful to ensure that data is stored in the correct partition subdirectories.

Comment: Thank you Chema for the detailed answer! I tried to run the `CREATE TABLE` statement and I get an error saying `AnalysisException: Table requires at least 1 column`

Comment: Hi @mongotop, in the ````create table```` you have to put fields that not belongs to the partitioned columns. For example ````CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kudu_parquet(
 name STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (year SMALLINT, month TINYINT, day TINYINT)
STORED AS PARQUET;````

Comment: I made some changes in the post to clarify the answer.

Comment: Thank you @chema for the clarification! I was hoping that I didn't have to specify the columns names for parquet table so my users will only have to create their Kudu tables and I will be able to create the parquet table for them on the fly automatically. like some sort of columns inheritance from Kudu. If it's not possible I think that would be a great feature to add to make sure the consistency is there and to avoid any user errors when creating the view that UNION Kudu and parquet tables. Data type errors, column names errors column order errors and such.

Comment: Hi @mongotop, that's interesting ```` that would be a great feature to add to make sure the consistency````, I think so too. If this post was useful, please accept the solution and upvote, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I was able to do it the simple way. just create table with all the columns names and data types, partitions with 0 initial default value for `YEAR`, MONTH and `DAY` and then I take the timestamps from Kudu table to extract `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY` to insert data in that partition. I something new come up I will come back to update the answer. Thank you again!